# Is it possible to get the 'Link: Mistral' mutation on Blade Dance or vice-versa?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, final-fantasy-explorers

I've been musing on the Combo Factor mutation, which states that two skills bearing the mutation used in succession will share a combo counter and thus get even further increased damage. The obvious candidates (among Dagger Skills) here being Blade Dance and Mistral, both of which able to gain the Combo Factor mutation, with the bonus of Mistral being also able to gain Multi-Hit for additional hits.

Is it possible to link these two skills in either order?